# Data Missing when using Netcat in C

Tags: c, string, netcat

I am having a C software for one of the embedded protocol. In this, I am need to redirect some events coming in callback functions to a TCP server. So, I thought of using Netcat and system command. Whenever the callback function fires, if I keep a string and forward it to netcat, then on TCP server I am getting data. But if I frame the command using the parameters in the callback function, only first time I am getting the data after that on TCP server am able to see on connection success and disconnect messages only.

My C code is

```
static void zwp_avi_interfaces_alarm_report_handler(zwifd_p ifd, zwalrm_p alarm_info, time_t ts)
{

    zwp_avi_interfaces_alarm_state_t *state;
    zwifd_p desc_interface;

    char systemcomm[1500];

    char tcp_buf[100];
    sprintf(tcp_buf,"echo 'node id: %d alarm type: %d alarm_event: %d", ifd->nodeid, alarm_info->ex_event, alarm_info->ex_has_sequence);
    strcat(systemcomm,tcp_buf);
    strcat(systemcomm," ' | netcat localhost 9091");
    system(systemcomm);

}
```

And output on TCP server is

```
A new connection has been established.
Data received from client: node id: 7 alarm type: 22 alarm_event: 0 

Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Closing connection with the client
```

In the code if I replace the last system fucntion call with be

```
system("echo 'alarm_event' | netcat localhost 9091");
```

Then I am getting how many times this callback fires those many times. Output in TCP server is as below

```
A new connection has been established.
Data received from client: alarm_event

Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Data received from client: alarm_event

Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Data received from client: alarm_event

Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Data received from client: alarm_event

Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Data received from client: alarm_event

Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Data received from client: alarm_event

Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Data received from client: alarm_event

Closing connection with the client
A new connection has been established.
Data received from client: alarm_event
```

Comment: Do you have the server's code as well?

Comment: Why use netcat? You can create a TCP socket pretty easily in C. Using `system` to do all the job is asking for trouble (or command injection).

Comment: Asides from the ugly mechanism I do not see a reason, why it should fail the way you describe. Maybe the bug is located in the server.

Answer (score 0):

`systemcomm` is not initialized, so `strcat(systemcomm,tcp_buf);` is an undefined behavior. Anything is possible. We may not even theorize what kind of initial garbage could cause such symptoms.

If you insist on `system`, just do a single

```
    sprintf(systemcomm, "echo '....' | netcat localhost 9091, ....);
```

Comment: `snprintf` would be better.